# How can I retrieve the full path of a trait bound in a Rust compiler plugin?

Tags: rust

I'm working on a Rust plugin that needs to access the absolute path of a trait bound. In practice, this means that for the following code, I want to resolve the full path of `Debug` as `std::fmt::Debug`.

```
use std::fmt::*;

#[foo]
trait Foo: Debug {}
```

My current approach consist of taking the `Annotatable` that `MultiItemDecorator` provides for me and pattern matching it to
`Annotatable::Item`, where I match `.node` to `ItemKind::Trait`. I then match `.generic_bounds` to a collection of `GenericBound::Trait`, where I retrieve `.trait_ref.path`.

This struct however only contains `path(Debug)`, which is not enough information for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

> ## [The Rustc Driver](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rustc-guide/rustc-driver.html):
>
> […] the main phases of the compiler are:
>
> 1. Parse Input: Initial crate parsing
> 2. Configure and Expand: Resolve `#[cfg]` attributes, name resolution, and **expand macros**
> 3. Run Analysis Passes: **Run trait resolution**, typechecking, region checking and other miscellaneous analysis passes on the crate
> 4. Translate to LLVM: Translate to the in-memory form of LLVM IR and turn it into an executable/object files

(emphasis is mine)

Macros are expanded before trait resolution is done, so at the time your plugin is run, nothing is known about this `Debug` except the name given in the source code.